# CRC32 calculation for serial communication

Tags: c, microcontroller, serial-communication, crc32

I was assigned to update the existing firmware with CRC32 from CRC8. The background is 2 MCUs communicating using serial communication. When I am doing some research online, I saw 2 versions of CRC calculation.
First version is

```
uint32_t  CalcCRC32(const uint8_t *pData, uint32_t length, uint32_t crc)
{
    const uint8_t *end = pData + length;

    while (pData < end)
    {
        crc ^= *pData++;

        for(i=0; i<8; i++){
           crc = crc & 0x80000000 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0x04C11DB7 : (crc << 1);
        }
    }

    return crc;
}
```

Second version is

```
uint32_t CRC32_function(uint8_t *pData, uint32_t len, uint32_t crc){

    uint32_t val, crc;
    uint8_t i;

    crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    while(len--){
        val=(crc^*pData++)&0xFF;
        for(i=0; i<8; i++){
            val = val & 0x1 ? (val>>1)^0xEDB88320 : val>>1;
        }
        crc = val^crc>>8;
    }
    return crc^0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

My assumption is I have to use first function for the first MCU and second function for second MCU since polynomial 0xEDB88320 is the reverse of 0x04C11DB7. Am I correct? If not, I would greatly appreciate for the suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you need to use the same at both ends or the value you calculate won't match!  However neither of these implementations is very fast.  If you can spare 1kB or ROM you can make a look-up-table and then do it a byte at a time instead of a bit at a time.

Comment: What uC? Maybe they suppoer hardware CRC

Comment: The first version seems to be processing bytes starting with the most significant bit. The second is least significant bit first, which probably explains the reversed polynomial. In any case, the two are not compatible.

Comment: You wish to try: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32 as it's okay and _fast_

Comment: Thanks all for the useful answers.

Comment: @0___________ It is PIC18. Already checked the datasheet and didn't see any hardware CRC. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and suggestion @TomV I saw a few look up table implementations on github and I am using one of them.

Comment: You might want to read [this guide](https://archive.org/stream/PainlessCRC/crc_v3.txt) to learn about CRC. Make sure you _understand_ what you do.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not correct. You would use the same function, or at least equivalent calculations, on both ends.

Those two functions calculate two entirely different CRC-32s. The second function is a pretty standard CRC-32, called [CRC-32/ISO-HDLC](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/all.htm#crc.cat.crc-32-iso-hdlc) in wide use, and is available with fast software implementations in [zlib](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/crc32.c) (much faster than the simple bit-wise function you show).

The first function computes a pure CRC that does not appear in that CRC catalog, but perhaps it was used in the application it came from with pre and post-processing to compute a CRC-32/BZIP2 or CRC-32/MPEG2.

Answer (score 1):

**Functional tip**

Use the same loop in both that transmitter and receiver.

**Speed tip**

With serial commination - if performed a 1 byte at a time, even at high baud, your CPU likely has lots of time to perform the CRC if the CRC was done a byte-at-a-time.

IOWs, calculate CRC while transmitting/receiving, not afterwards.

Pseudo code

```
Set-up initial `crc` state.
While there is data to receive/transmit
  send/receiver one byte in `*pData`
  val = (crc ^ *pData++) & 0xFF;
  for (i=0; i<8; i++){
    val = val & 0x1 ? (val>>1)^0xEDB88320 : val>>1;
  }
  crc = val ^ crc>>8;
}
Finish CRC.
```

Now your CRC calculation will not take a bunch of time after the last byte - an improvement in latency.